# LSF serial jobs on HPC performance worse than local sequential executions

Tags: hpc, lsf

I'm learning how to use HPC on our lab's clusters, which uses LSF. I tried a simple serial jobs each of which count the frequency of the words in a text file. I wrote a python code for counting the word frequency named count_word_freq.py, a jobs script named myjob.job as following:

```
python count_word_freq.py --in ~/books/1.txt --out ~/freqs/freq1.txt
python count_word_freq.py --in ~/books/2.txt --out ~/freqs/freq2.txt
python count_word_freq.py --in ~/books/3.txt --out ~/freqs/freq3.txt
python count_word_freq.py --in ~/books/4.txt --out ~/freqs/freq4.txt
python count_word_freq.py --in ~/books/5.txt --out ~/freqs/freq5.txt
```

and a lsf script to submit the serial jobs to the selfscheduler:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J test01
#BSUB -P acc_pandeg01a
#BSUB -q alloc
#BSUB -W 20
#BSUB -n 20
#BSUB -m manda
#BSUB -o %J.stdout
#BSUB -eo %J.stderr
#BSUB -L /bin/bash
module load python
module load py_packages
module load selfsched
# And run the program; output will be on stdout
mpirun selfsched < myjobs001.jobs
```

The python code is as following:

```
def readBookAsFreqDict(infile):
    dic = {}
    with open(infile,"r") as file:
        for line in file:
            contents = line.split(" ")
            for cont in contents:
                if str.isalpha(cont):
                    if cont not in dic.keys():
                        dic[cont] = 1
                    else:
                        dic[cont] = dic[cont] + 1
    return dic

import sys
import argparse
import time as T
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = T.time()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--i', type=str, help = 'input file')
    parser.add_argument('--o', type=str, help = 'output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    dic = readBookAsFreqDict(args.i)
    outfile = open(args.o,"w")
    for key,freq in dic.iteritems():
       outfile.write(key + ":" + str(freq) + "\n")
    end = T.time()
    print (end - start)
```

The 5 input texts are almost the same size of around 3.5 MB. My question is that the CPU time for running this serial job is 980s, which is worse than running it sequentially.

To my understanding, the selfscheduler can automatically assign the 5 jobs to empty nodes, thus can save the running time for running it sequentially. Is that because the execution time for each job is too short compared to the time to find an empty node? Is there any other approaches can be used to make it faster?

Thank you!

Comment: are all 5 jobs running on the same node? maybe you need `-x -R "span[ptile=1]"`

Comment: I created huge text files for testing. When I test just one file locally, the running time is about 46min, when i ran 5 files on lsf  exactly the same code above but only different size of text file, the job completed in less than 2 hours, but the CPU time showed 6 hours in the stdout file. So is CPU time the sum of the time spent on each node?

Comment: @MichaelClosson Thank for your suggestion. I'm not sure if they are running on the same node, but probably not.

Comment: Resource usage summary:

    CPU time :                                   23578.00 sec.
    Max Memory :                                 1109 MB
    Average Memory :                             981.82 MB
    Total Requested Memory :                     81920.00 MB
    Delta Memory :                               80811.00 MB
    Max Processes :                              54
    Max Threads :                                135